# Python Sqlalchemy counting duplicate results in query

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a query

```
allcategory =  db.session.query(func.count(marketItem.subcategory).label("help"),Subcategories.subname1)
allcategory = allcategory.join(Subcategories)
allcategory = allcategory.filter(marketItem.subcategory == Subcategories.id)
allcategory = allcategory.filter(marketItem.vendor_id==vendorprofile.id)
allcategory = allcategory.group_by(marketItem.id)
for allcat in allcategory.all():
    print(allcat)
```

thats outputs the results as

```
(1, 'Consoles')
(1, 'Consoles')
(1, 'Paintings')
(1, 'Paintings')
(1, 'Paintings')
```

I would like them to be

```
(2, 'Consoles')
(3, 'Paintings')
```

If it could also be explained in regular sql terms, that would help as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be grouping by `Subcategory.subname1`:

```
allcategory =  db.session.query(func.count(marketItem.subcategory).label("help"),
                                Subcategories.subname1)
allcategory = allcategory.join(Subcategories)
allcategory = allcategory.filter(marketItem.subcategory==Subcategories.id)
allcategory = allcategory.filter(marketItem.vendor_id==vendorprofile.id)
allcategory = allcategory.group_by(Sucategories.subname1) # < change here
for allcat in allcategory.all():
    print(allcat)
```

In SQL you must group by the fields that are not being aggregated -- in this case `Subcategories.subname1`.